# Flutter RadioListTile change Radio(icon) color

Tags: flutter, radio-button

I have trouble changing Radio List Tile icon color.
I tried to use ListTileTheme but not worked.
By the way, I'm using RadioListTile in a dialog but I don't think that this affects it.

Code.

```
ListTileTheme(
   iconColor: AppColors.green,
   textColor: AppColors.green,
   child: SimpleDialog(
   shape:
   RoundedRectangleBorder(
   borderRadius:
   BorderRadius
   .circular(10),
   ),
   title: Text(
   "Select Restaurant",
   style: Theme.of(context)
   .textTheme
   .headline3,
   textAlign:
   TextAlign.center,
   ),
   children: [
   Divider(),
   RadioListTile(
   title: const Text(
   'Name and Address'),
   value: 1,
   groupValue:
   _isRadioSelected,
   onChanged: (v) {
   setState(() {
   _isRadioSelected =
   v;
   });
   },
   ),
   ],
   ),
   );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.green,
            disabledColor: Colors.green
        ),
        child: RadioListTile(
          title: const Text('Name and Address'),
          value: 1,
          groupValue: _isRadioSelected,
          onChanged: (v) {
            setState(() {
              _isRadioSelected = v;
            });
          },
        ),
      )
```

---

Use Theme for change some theme param in current widget.
[image]

Comment: unselectedWidgetColor and disabledColor not worked. Actually, It works with changing the toggleableActiveColor property.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a custom simple radio list widget by using the below code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp(),
  ));
}

class GroupModel {
  String text;
  int index;
  bool selected;

  GroupModel({this.text, this.index, this.selected});
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => new _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyApp> {
  int _value2 = 0;
  List<GroupModel> _group = [
    GroupModel(text: "Item 1", index: 1, selected: true),
    GroupModel(text: "Item 2", index: 2, selected: false),
    GroupModel(text: "Item 3", index: 3, selected: false),
  ];

  Widget makeRadioTileList() {
    List<Widget> list = new List<Widget>();

    for (int i = 0; i < _group.length; i++) {
      list.add(new RadioListTile(
        value: _group[i].index,
        groupValue: _value2,
        selected: _group[i].selected,
        onChanged: (val) {
          setState(() {
            for (int i = 0; i < _group.length; i++) {
              _group[i].selected = false;
            }
            _value2 = val;
            _group[i].selected = true;
          });
        },
        activeColor: Colors.purple,
        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
        title: new Text(
          ' ${_group[i].text}',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: _group[i].selected ? Colors.black : Colors.grey,
              fontWeight:
                  _group[i].selected ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal),
        ),
      ));
    }

    Column column = new Column(
      children: list,
    );
    return column;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('RadioListTile Example'),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: new Center(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[makeRadioTileList()],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```